# PostgreSQL: load a file from filesystem without inserting into a table

Tags: mysql, postgresql, file-io

How do I do such a thing?
In mysql I do:

```
SELECT LOAD_FILE('/path/to/file');
```

What about postgres? Without using the `\copy` command of psql?

Comment: What exactly is the use case of this? It seems like an odd thing to want to do..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends what you want to do exactly.

- You have [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) for reading structured data into (temporary) tables.
  <sub>Note that this is the SQL command, which is similar, but not the same as the \copy command of psql!</sub>
- And there is [pg_read_file()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) for reading in any text file.

#### Edit - a basic example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_showfile(myfile text)
  RETURNS text AS
$x$
BEGIN

RETURN pg_read_file(myfile, 0, 1000000); -- 1 MB max.
-- or you could read into a text var and do stuff with it.

END;
$x$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Only superusers can use this function. Be careful not to open security holes. You could create a function with [`SECURITY DEFINER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html), `REVOKE FROM`public and `GRANT TO` selected roles. If security is an issue **read** this paragraph at the provided link:

> Writing SECURITY DEFINER Functions Safely

`pg_read_file()` you can only read from the logfile dir and the database dir. On *Linux* you could create a symlink to a data dir (at a safe location) like this:

```
cd /path//my/database
ln -s /var/lib/postgresql/text_dir/ .
```

Then call like this:

```
SELECT f_showfile('text_dir/readme.txt');
```

Output:

```
                                            f_showfile
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 This is my text from a file.
```

Comment: I'd need an example on how to use the copy statement :( I really can't achieve to print from the postgres shell a user file I need.